# I want to scan 2 datum and see if it has relevancy or not

Tags: javascript

So I want to scan 2 Datum, these are texts, then I will rate it if it has relevancy.

Example:

```
Data: individual facts
Data: statistics, items of information individual facts
```

This is my JS code that will scan the whole webpage:

```
var listitem, thislist;
var itemname = new Array();
listitem = getElementsByClass('Forwards');
for(var i = 0; i < listitem.length; i++) {  
  if (listitem[i].innerHTML.match(/Data:/)) itemname.push(listitem[i].innerHTML);
}
```

So the itemname array contains the texts. The first array contains:

```
Data: individual facts
```

The second array contains:

```
Data: statistics, items of information individual facts
```

As you can see the second array contains more information:

```
Data: statistics, items of information
```

But they are relevant right?

So I want to return `TRUE`

How would I code this?

Comment: Relevant to what?  Where is the second list? Can you provide an example?

Comment: The first list is "Data: individual facts"; the second list is "Data: statistics, items of information individual facts" I want to compare those two, if one of the list contains the same information as the other list then I want the program to return true. Else false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your data conforms to "Data: [data Element], [data Element]..." -- after the initial colon individual elements are separated by a comma.

So, what you want to do is extract the data (everything after the colon) and break it down into individuals (everything between commas)

```
    function ProcessDatum(datum){
    var str = datum.toString();
    var dataPieces = str.substr(str.indexOf(':')).split(',');
    return dataPieces;
}

    function CompareData(first, second){
    // Do your usual array compare stuff, I don't know what would be best for you
    // What you want to do is to check if any element of second appears in first
}
```

ProcessDatum() will give you an array of the individual data from your original "Data: first, second, third". CompareData() on two datasets to process.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this simpler, I just want to a script that will scan the strings. Then if it find a 2 matches, it will return true.

For example if string 1 = "Blue big doll" then string 2 = "Blue doll". Both of the have "BLUE" & "doll" inside their string, so it will return true. If string 2 = "BLUE" it will return false because the condition is 2 matches.